# Best practice to move local files to BLOB (copy / verify / delete)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a local Integration runtime installed on a client machine (MS Server 2012R2) with access to a local folder there. Another program spits out .csv files periodically ~ 1 every 5 minutes.
I need to copy them as is to blob storage (binaries is fine). Once they are successfully copied i need to go back and delete just those files that were uploaded i.e. do not delete any files that may have been added since the pipeline run started.

I know there's no 'move' activity in ADF and I've seen some different ways to couple together copy & delete activities with a ForEach to do a move but am unsure of best practice.

I'm trying to do all of this in the UI (no code) and have no problem doing a simple file copy or delete activity - im just unsure of how to link them together with a ForEach - or if thats even the best approach?

expected results is to handle when there's no files to copy but if there is ADF should copy all files available then delete only those that were copied successfully.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: if my answer helps you,you could accept it for answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Provide two ways for your references:

First one,as you mentioned in your question,using **Azure Data Factory**.

You could use Copy Activity to transfer data from on-premise folder into Azure Blob Storage. Then use [Delete Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity) to delete files in the on-premise folder.

Run the entire pipeline in the schedule, follow this [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/incrementally-copy-new-files-by-lastmodifieddate-with-azure-data-factory/) to filter files by the file latest modified time.Between copy activity and delete activity, use [if-condition activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity)  to control the transmission process. If the copy activity has been executed successfully, delete actions will be continued.

Second one,using **Az Copy**.

Az copy could migrate on-premises data to cloud storage. (Detailed [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-migrate-on-premises-data?tabs=linux#create-a-scheduled-task))

Below example command recursively copies data from a local directory to a blob container. A fictitious SAS token is appended to the end of the of the container URL.

```
azcopy cp "C:\local\path" "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1/?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bjqt&srt=sco&sp=rwddgcup&se=2019-05-01T05:01:17Z&st=2019-04-30T21:01:17Z&spr=https&sig=MGCXiyEzbtttkr3ewJIh2AR8KrghSy1DGM9ovN734bQF4%3D" --recursive=true
```

You still could run the az copy command in the schedule: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-migrate-on-premises-data?tabs=linux#create-a-scheduled-task

In addition,you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-choose-data-transfer-solution?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json) to get know about multiple Azure solution for data transfer.